# How to react when an externally played FLV reaches Nth frame or percentage?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, flv

I have this custom video player I'm making. I need some way to react when the externally played flv file reaches a certain point in the movie without embedding some extra data on the flv file. I am looking for this because I want to react at the 90%-99% point of the movie because I didn't like the behavior I'm getting when I react when the stream completes playing (I want a bit earlier). How do I achieve this?

I'm surprised Adobe didn't document what is the object structure passed on things like onMetaData and onCuePoint...

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a little math. Position of play head divided by duration multiply by 100.

If value is greater than 90 fire your event.

```
((p / d) * 100)
```

Comment: Pretty sure I ran into a problem with this. The video guy I worked with was encoding the meta-data at the end of the file and not in the beginning before I was hired. So needless to say duration didn't exist messing up progress bar until the file fully downloaded. The video guy ended up having to encode all the videos he did.

Comment: Uhh yeah, I know the math. But the problem is where to retrieve the current position and maximum position.

Comment: So can you obtain any metadata? If you have proper metadata you should be able to read the duration after the first few seconds are buffered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by programmatically setting a cue point based on the length the movie clip, then creating an event listener for it.

```
var endpoint:Number = flvPlayer.metadata.duration*.95; //95% of the video length
flvPlayer.addASCuePoint(endpoint, "endpoint");

flvPlayer.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, registerCuePoints);

function registerCuePoints(myEvent:MetadataEvent) {
    if(myEvent.info.name == "endpoint") {
    // you've reached your cue point, not something embedded in the video.
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice, but I want to point out this is only for the FLVPlayback component.

Comment: The endpoint is valid, but ActionScript cue points aren't very accurate. If accuracy is needed, checking on a playhead update would be safer.

Comment: Like I said, I need a solution that is:
- Non FLVPlayback component
- Doesn't require embed cuepoints on the FLV file.